how to validate form textarea have at least 12 characters with bootstrap?
I'm working on the form of website. I'm getting user id, topic, body from user in a form. I'm using bootstrap to validate topic with at least one non white space character. The body should have at least 12 characters excluding leading and trailing white spaces. It prints error message when user does not meet the requirements. However, I cannot get the body to have at least 12 characters.


(function () {
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (event) {
        var feedback = document.getElementById("customvalidation");
        var body = document.getElementById("body");
        var min_text = 12;
        //trim leading and trailing white space
        var length = body.value.trim().length;

        if (!form.checkValidity() || length < min_text) {          
          feedback.textContent = `body requires minimum ${min_text} characters`;
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        form.classList.add("was-validated");
      },
      false
    );
  });
})();
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="id" class="col-form-label">User ID</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="id"
        placeholder="User ID..."
        maxlength="15"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="topic" class="col-form-label">Topic</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="topic"
        placeholder="What is it about..."
        required
        pattern=".*\S+.*"
      />
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        input at least one non white space character
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="body" class="col-form-label">Body</label>
      <textarea
        class="form-control"
        id="body"
        placeholder="Write something..."
        rows="10"
        required
      ></textarea>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" id="customvalidation"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    </body>
    </html>




I solved the problem by adding a function to check if the textarea input has greater than 12 characters, excluding leading and trailing white spaces


//validates contact form
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var form = document.querySelector(".needs-validation");
  var textarea = document.getElementById("body");

  form.addEventListener(
    "submit",
    function (event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity() || !isValidInput(textarea.value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }

      form.classList.add("was-validated");
    },
    false
  );
  //set textarea validity based on input
  textarea.addEventListener("input", function () {
    if (isValidInput(this.value)) {
      this.setCustomValidity("");
    } else {
      this.setCustomValidity("Invalid input");
    }
  });
  //ensure body is at least 12 characters
  function isValidInput(value) {
    return value.trim().length >= 12;
  }
})();
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="id" class="col-form-label">User ID</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="id"
        placeholder="User ID..."
        maxlength="15"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="topic" class="col-form-label">Topic</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="topic"
        placeholder="What is it about..."
        required
        pattern=".*\S+.*"
      />
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        input at least one non white space character
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="body" class="col-form-label">Body</label>
      <textarea
        class="form-control"
        id="body"
        placeholder="Write something..."
        rows="10"
        required
      ></textarea>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" id="customvalidation">body requires at least 12 characters</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    </body>
    </html>




Indeed, good point!

Wouldn't it be possible to add the minimum size directly to the pattern? ^\S{12,}$
this regex means starts and ends with some character other than space and is at least 12 in length

Adding a minLength attribute on the textarea with a value of 12 (or a desired value) solves your issue.

min length would allow white space. I do not want to allow the textarea to be all white space.

<input type="text" name="" id="test" value="" minLength="12" required/>


If not using javascript put minLength="12" in input tag

 function(){
      let data = document.getElementById('test').value
      if(data.length<=12) {
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 'Error';
      }
       else {  
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';
      }
 }


for custom message. In javascript get input filed value by using DOM, and validate input value length

